# Div with dynamic remaining height and scrollbar

Tags: css, html, scroll, overflow

I'm trying to get a solution for my special problem.
I got 2 div's, the first one is the header with a dynamic height.
The second div should fill up the remaining space of the page, and if the content is too large, a scrollbar should appear.

The problem is, my solution for putting the height of the second div doesn't fit with the scrollbar.

It's hard to explain, take a look at my code, I made comments so you should get my problem.

HTML:

```
    <div id="header_with_dynamic_height">
        This<br/>is<br/>the<br/>header<br/>content.
    </div>
    <div id="remaining_height_with_scrollbar">
        Here<br/>should<br/>be<br/>a<br/>scrollbar.<br/>
        But<br/>the<br/>content<br/>overlaps.<br/>
        1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>10<br/>
        1<br/>2<br/>3<br/>4<br/>5<br/>6<br/>7<br/>8<br/>9<br/>10<br/>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    html, body {
        margin: 0; padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
    }
    #header_with_dynamic_height {
        background-color: blue;
        float: left; width: 100%;
    }
    #remaining_height_with_scrollbar {
        background-color: green;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: none;
        /* If you change this to "scroll" or "auto", the content disappears */
    }
```

Please see also http://jsfiddle.net/T3qF8/2/.
Change the overflow to "auto" or "scroll" like it should be and see how the whole second div disappears. Why does this happen? I don't find a solution for this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<div class="table container">
    <div class="table-row header">
        <div>This is the header whose height is unknown</div>
        <div>This is the header whose height is unknown</div>
        <div>This is the header whose height is unknown</div>
    </div>
    <div class="table-row body">
        <div class="table-cell body-content-outer-wrapper">
            <div class="body-content-inner-wrapper">
                <div class="body-content">
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                    <div>This is the scrollable content whose height is unknown</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    display: table;
}

.table-row {
    display: table-row;
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
}

.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
}

.header {
    background: cyan;
}

.body {
    background: yellow;
    height: 100%;
}

.body-content-outer-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
}

.body-content-inner-wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}

.body-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

From: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kurlak/archive/2015/02/20/filling-the-remaining-height-of-a-container-while-handling-overflow-in-css.aspx

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/352ntoz2/

Answer (score 2):

You have to use width: 100% in your div and overflow: hidden; in the body

```
#remaining_height_with_scrollbar {
   background-color: green;
   height: 100%;
   overflow: scroll;
   width: 100%;
   /* If you change this to "scroll" or "auto", the content disappears */
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/T3qF8/3/

Comment: After this I get a scrollbar, but the second div takes too much height and not only the remaining space. It doesn't take the remaining height, but the window height.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem, but only with the use of a table layout:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vedkw/68/

```
display:table;
```

But a solution without tables would be much better.

Comment: @SBBS Here's a cross-browser solution: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kurlak/archive/2015/02/20/filling-the-remaining-height-of-a-container-while-handling-overflow-in-css.aspx and fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/352ntoz2/